# xcode shows type as "id" rather than the original type in Code Sense

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I don't know why it happens, but sometimes xcode Code Sense shows me type of the object as "id" rather than the actual type. I have declared a property of mutable array and synthesized it, released it in -dealloc(), nowhere in my code it has been used, neither any other code contains any errors, (xcode doesn't show a single warning either).
  Still, when I open Code Sense of this object, it shows its type as id, not as NSMutableArray.

Comment: Xcode does not have any feature called `Intellisense` - what you most likely mean is called `Code Sense`.

Comment: :| sorry, I didn't knew the exact name it is called. Any way, Yeh, the Code Sense, (the list shown when pressing Esc). Do you know the reason why the Code Sense doesn't show the exact type?

Comment: Does anyone know why this happens and what solution might work?